# How can I use TypeScript to change the mint authority of a token account?

Tags: web3.js

I know it is possible to change the mint authority using `solana-spl` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72284208/is-it-possible-to-transfer-minting-authority-of-a-solana-token-to-another-accoun). How can I achieve the same thing using TypeScript/JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `setAuthority` from `@solana/spl-token` and select `AuthorityType.MintTokens`

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#setAuthority

For example, something like this:

```
  const transactionSignature = await setAuthority(
    connection,
    payer,
    tokenMint,
    payer.publicKey, // current authority goes here (must also be signer)
    AuthorityType.MintTokens,
    newMintAuthority.publickey // new authority goes here
  )
```

You can also use `createSetAuthorityInstruction` if you want to just create the instruction and add then to a transaction.

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#createSetAuthorityInstruction

Comment: Hi John,
I am attempting to change the mintAuthority from the current mintAddress to null. However, during the execution, I encountered a "signature verification failed" error.

 const transactionSignature = await setAuthority(
        connection,   //connection
        userWallet,   // wallet Address
        mintPubkey,   //tokenMintAddress
        mintPubkey, // current authority goes here (must also be signer)
        AuthorityType.MintTokens,
        null
    )